# Is there a database for translated Drama CD Scripts?

Tags: resources

a number of Anime like *Magical Girl Lyrical Nanoha*, *Pella Magi Madoka Magica*, *Fate/Stay Night* and Games like *Ar Tonelico*, *Sono Hanabira* and *Megaman Zero* have some soundtracks which are actually Audio Drama's<sup>1</sup>.

These are more often than not in Japanese. i am wondering if there is a single database/store for their translated scripts, primarily in English.

---

<sup>1: eg. Nanoha has *Sound Stage X*, Ar Tonelico has *Sekai no Owari de Utai Tsuzukeru Shoujo* (that's what the Meta Data for "Album Title" is on my iPhone). one of the Megaman Zero ones was of Ceil's Memories before she fled Neo Arcadia and one was of the Weil Numbers acting as Judges i think and one of the Puella Magi Madoka Magica ones served as the basis for the manga *Another Story*</sup>

Comment: I am not aware of any English-language database of drama CDs at all, let alone one which includes translations (which is possibly a violation of our policy not to answer questions requesting pirated versions of copyright materials anyway, but that's a bit besides the point).  Even in Japanese, the best sources I know of are quite spotty.

Comment: @LoganM a CD would generally have the script printed on a small booklet or some sort in a similar matter to lyrics with Music CDs so i would assume that it's kinda redundant to have a database of Japanese scripts, unless it was used by media programs like iTunes and Windows Media Player to download the meta data (for when you rip the tracks from the disk)

Comment: I don't think any of the drama CDs I own came with scripts. In any case, I'd imagine that copying the script online (either in original form or as a translated derivative work) would technically constitute copyright violation, and would likely be viewed somewhat more harshly than e.g. posting lyrics online. The databases that I am aware of in Japanese don't include scripts, and I don't think it would be kosher for them to do so (either original or translation).

Comment: Concur with Logan; I am unaware of any cases where drama CDs come with printed scripts. (And I am also unaware of any drama CDs that have been translated to English by a licensed entity, though I wouldn't be terribly surprised if a few did exist.)

Comment: @senshin I just assumed those books I got did contain the script since music CDs in the west generally do contain their lyrics but unable to read Japanese I wasn't sure (I just skip to the images)

Comment: Music CDs in Japan do tend to come with lyrics, too, but drama CDs aren't really "music", per se.